# Unable to open WampServer's config file, please change path in index.php file

Tags: php, wamp, wampserver

> Unable to open WampServer's config file, please change path in index.php file.

How to solve this problem in my windows?

Comment: Well, show us the `index.php`.

Comment: take a look here http://w3schools.invisionzone.com/index.php?showtopic=31467

Comment: I dont understand by w3schools.invisionzone.com/index.php?showtopic=31467 – antoniom and my index file are many line so i couldn't post here.

Comment: do you have the file `wampmanager.conf` in `c:\wamp` folder ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to change index.php and don't use index.php located in www.